# Issue with redoing clearcase ucm rebase

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

I did a rebase of one stream from its parent and there were conflicts. So, I resolved the conflcits manually but selected wrong versions of some files while resolving conflcits and rebased was completed. is this possible to redo this again or I have to manually merge the files one by one to get correct version ? this is for clearcase-ucm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is easily done on your existing stream.

That means:

- either you can recreate another child stream, based on the same foundation baseline as the one stream you used for your rebase, and try again in that new child stream
- or, if this is only for a few files, [get an older version of those files](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8358070/6309) (or [use a separate dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44583657/6309)), and [merge them manually](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49199013/6309).
  If needed, you can add [red merge arrow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2397867/6309) later to mark the merges between the source and destination versions of those files.